# Acces a variable before redefining it in a closure in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code

```
var scope = "global scope";
function checkscope() {
    console.log(scope);
    var scope = "local scope";
    console.log(scope);
}
checkscope();
```

This prints the following in the console

```
undefined
local scope
```

Why is the first `console.log` printing `undefined` instead of `"global scope"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). Your `var` keyword is hoisting a new local `scope` variable to the top of the function, which is undefined.

Your code is the same as:

```
function checkscope() {
    var scope;
    console.log(scope);
    scope = "local scope";
    console.log(scope);
}
```

To access the global `scope` from within the function, you would have to reference the global object, which is `window` for browsers. This will work if the global `scope` is actually global, and not just in a parent scope of `checkscope()`.

```
function checkscope() {
    console.log(window.scope); // access the global
    var scope = "local scope";
    console.log(scope);
}
```

- [MDN docs for hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: And is there a way to acces the variable containing `global scope`?

Comment: `var scope; // initially undefined`

Comment: @devian if it's _truly_ global, then `window.scope` would work.  But don't do that unless you really have to.

Comment: @devian if you want to access the local `scope` variable from the global scope then no it's not accessible. If you want to access the global `scope` variable from in the function then `window.scope` will work.